# What are the wings and fuselage of an airliner made of?

Tags: airliner, aerospace-materials

Which materials are used to make the wings and the fuselage of an airliner, for example the Boeing 767 or the Airbus A320?

Comment: this risks being a tad broad, all possible steel/aluminium/titanium alloys + fiber composites are quite a lot. But I concede that only a finite list is used for the fuselage/wings. Let's see what the answers bring, but if you could think of a way to narrow it down a bit, I think it might help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most modern planes are made mostly of [aircraft aluminum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/6061_aluminium_alloy). Or at least are skinned in aluminum. The spars and cross members may be made of other materials but I am under the impression they are mainly aluminum as well. Generally high stress areas like wing/fuselage joints may be made of more rigid materials like steel. Aircraft Spruce provides a nice [break down of the various types of aluminum here](http://www.aircraftspruce.com/catalog/mepages/aluminfo.php). This answer to a similar question [provides a nice break down](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/12960/3677).

As the technology gets better and the facilities grow in both scale and ability, [composites like carbon fiber have found their place in planes like the 787](http://www.boeing.com/commercial/aeromagazine/articles/qtr_4_06/article_04_2.html). Here is a break down for the 787

[image]
([source](http://www.boeing.com/commercial/aeromagazine/articles/qtr_4_06/images/article_04_chart1.gif))

Comment: The "source" link would be more useful if it pointed to the [document where the image is embedded](http://www.boeing.com/commercial/aeromagazine/articles/qtr_4_06/article_04_2.html) rather than being just a link to the bare gif.